# Anyone know if 12.04 has OpenGL Aux Libraries?

Tags: 12.04, programming, opengl, c++, libraries

Im wanting to know how to install ubuntu 12.04's OpenGL aux libraries if any. Im trying to program OpenGL with C++. I cant find anything on google so.

any help would be super great!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, why aren't you using GLUT? The [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/gettingstarted.htm) *hates* AUX:

> #### 2.130 What is the AUX library?
>
> Very important: Don't use AUX. Use GLUT instead.
>
> The AUX library was developed by SGI early in OpenGL's life to ease creation of small OpenGL demonstration programs. It's currently neither supported nor maintained. Developing OpenGL programs using AUX is strongly discouraged. Use the GLUT instead. It's more flexible and powerful and is available on a wide range of platforms.

Long-unsupported software has a habit of not being packaged or (if it has already), being removed.

From what I'm starting to gather from reading around, GLAUX was never supported on Linux and is long-since dead on Windows.

Follow the advice of the FAQ and use GLUT (libglui et al).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I still dont know if FreeGLUT has Keyboard and Mouse functions like AUX has. or similiar.

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking at SDL or an engine like Ogre3D. I don't know what your focus is... If you're trying to learn the basics GLUT/SDL will be fine but if you're just after something you can push to multiple platforms quickly, look at the more abstracting libraries like Ogre.

Comment: thanks! ill try to find a way to implement SDL into OpenGL. IDK. blah